# How I use accumulate function from dplyr to rowwise reproduce a data frame or tibble in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to reproduce the following table from Hull's book Options & Derivatives.

I believe that accumulate function from `dplyr` might be suitable but I cannot reproduce it.

my effort is the following.

```
library(tidyverse)
initial_deposit = 12000
contract_value = 9000
closing_stock_indices = c(1250,1241,1238.3,1244.6,1241.3,1240.1, 1236.2, 1229.9,
                         1230.8,1225.4,1228.1,1211,1211,1214.3,1216.1,1223,1226.9)

(seq_along(closing_stock_indices) - 1) %>%
 as.data.frame() %>%
 setNames('Day') %>%
 mutate(Closing_SI = closing_stock_indices,
        Daily_change = c(0, diff(Closing_SI*200)),
        Cum_gain = cumsum( Daily_change),
        Margin_balance = accumulate(Cum_gain[-1], .init = initial_deposit,
                                    ~ if (.x >= initial_deposit).x + .y else initial_deposit + .y),
        Variation_Margin = -1 * pmin(Margin_balance - initial_deposit, 0),
        margin_call = c(0, Variation_Margin[-n()]))
```

[image]

or

```
tibble(closing_stock_indices)%>%
 dplyr::mutate(Day = row_number())%>%
 mutate(Close =closing_stock_indices )%>%
 dplyr::mutate(y = as.numeric( Close - (dplyr::lag(Close, 1))))%>%
 dplyr::select(-closing_stock_indices)%>%
 dplyr::mutate(y = replace_na(y,0),
               Cum_gain = 200*cumsum(y))%>%
 dplyr::mutate(Margin_balance = initial_deposit+Cum_gain)
```

Is there any other alternative using `rowwise()` from `dplyr`?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your first code block is incomplete/broken, can you please fix it?

Comment: @r2evans I have edited it. To be honest I prefer the second one (block) that has pure dplyr functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `accumulate` over the daily change not the cumulative change, otherwise you are cumulating twice. I have used a base lambda function instead of the purrr one for expressiveness:

```r
library(tidyverse)
initial_deposit = 12000
contract_value = 9000
closing_stock_indices = c(1250,1241,1238.3,1244.6,1241.3,1240.1, 1236.2, 1229.9,
                          1230.8,1225.4,1228.1,1211,1211,1214.3,1216.1,1223,1226.9)



(seq_along(closing_stock_indices) - 1) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('Day') %>%
  mutate(
    Closing_SI = closing_stock_indices,
    Daily_change = c(0, diff(Closing_SI*200)),
    Cum_gain = cumsum(Daily_change),
    Margin_balance = accumulate(
      Daily_change[-1], 
      .init = initial_deposit,
      \(bal, gain) if (bal > contract_value) bal + gain
                   else initial_deposit + gain
      ),
    margin_call = ifelse(Margin_balance < contract_value, 
                         initial_deposit - Margin_balance, 
                         0)
    )
#>    Day Closing_SI Daily_change Cum_gain Margin_balance margin_call
#> 1    0     1250.0            0        0          12000           0
#> 2    1     1241.0        -1800    -1800          10200           0
#> 3    2     1238.3         -540    -2340           9660           0
#> 4    3     1244.6         1260    -1080          10920           0
#> 5    4     1241.3         -660    -1740          10260           0
#> 6    5     1240.1         -240    -1980          10020           0
#> 7    6     1236.2         -780    -2760           9240           0
#> 8    7     1229.9        -1260    -4020           7980        4020
#> 9    8     1230.8          180    -3840          12180           0
#> 10   9     1225.4        -1080    -4920          11100           0
#> 11  10     1228.1          540    -4380          11640           0
#> 12  11     1211.0        -3420    -7800           8220        3780
#> 13  12     1211.0            0    -7800          12000           0
#> 14  13     1214.3          660    -7140          12660           0
#> 15  14     1216.1          360    -6780          13020           0
#> 16  15     1223.0         1380    -5400          14400           0
#> 17  16     1226.9          780    -4620          15180           0
```